# how to add or set up two log paths for logging in laravel or lumen?

Tags: laravel, logging, lumen, monolog

There is provision to change log paths according to log levels. But what if, i have two different path for log files each contains log with all levels or custom configured level?

For example I have two paths for Api Logs and Sms Logs having different path.

How can i define two logs? currently logging is done like
ex

> `Log::emergency('Log string');`

This string is logged according to defined stream handler of emergency level.

But instead i want this log to write in API path log or Sms path log.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel used the Monolog as far as I can remember, go ahead and check that out. Monolog is really flexible and gives you a ton of control.

If you want to use Monolog's advanced features, I assume you can just do it out of the box as advertised:

use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;

$view_log = new Logger('View Logs');

// used the different path for laravel or lumen
$view_log->pushHandler(new StreamHandler('path/to/log.log', Logger::INFO));

$view_log->addInfo("User $user clicked");

Comment: Hi saidur, i am using lumen to create rest based api. where can i code this custom logger , i mean where can i bootstrap this code and how can i access different loggers in whole project?